# Connecting DHT11 sensor

Tags: gpio, sensor

I want to use the DHT11 sensor with my Raspberry PI 2 Model B.

I'm using pin#01 for the VCC, pin#39 for GND, but I don't know which pin should I use for DATA? Should I enable some GPIO ports to use them? I get only 0x0 data (I tried pin#37).

[image]

Comment: You don't mention what if any tutorial you are using, but have you tried this https://learn.adafruit.com/dht-humidity-sensing-on-raspberry-pi-with-gdocs-logging/overview

Comment: Yes, I tried this Adafruit tutorial, but I get 0x0 data only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any GPIO you want.

I have some example software at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD to read the DHT series of temperature and humidity sensors.  It should auto detect the sensor type.  It requires my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library.

Connect Pi 3V3 to sensor +, Pi ground to sensor ground, and any GPIO to sensor data.  You ALSO need to connect a 4k7 (or thereabouts) resistor between the data line and 3V3.  The sensor will not work otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me can I use 5V for the sensor? I read the sensor's specification and it says if I use 5V I can send the signal to 20m, which is great because I want to deploy other sensors inside the house.

Comment: It should be possible to do as follows: Connect Pi 5V to sensor +, Pi ground to sensor ground, and any GPIO to sensor data. You ALSO need to connect a 4k7 (or thereabouts) resistor between the data line and 3V3.  In other words leave the data line pull-up connected to 3V3 but power from 5V.  I have not tested this but I'm told it will work by those who know more than me.

Comment: So I can use 5V too. Should I use other resistor? And can I use multiple sensors with sharing the 3.3/5V and ground and separating data lines for each sensor?

Comment: @Panthesilea The same value resistor will be fine.  You can share the power and ground lines between sensors.  You will need a separate resistor for each data line pull-up to 3V3, and each data line will need its own GPIO.