# elecrow sensors on i2c serial line

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, i2c, sensor

I have elecrow's sensors like [this one](https://www.elecrow.com/crowtail-am2302-humiditytemperature-sensor-p-1651.html) that I want connect to i2c hub and use it based on the address.

first I'm trying to set my pi 3b+ to recognize at least one of them connected directly.

I'm on raspbian and I have turned on I2C, even SPI in `raspi-config`.
`#i2cdetect -y 1` shows nothing connected

so, I want to check here whenther I can connect sensor like that directly to +5V, GND, SDA1, SLC1 and it should work or I am missing something?

thanks for advices.

Comment: Your Elecrow's sensor seems to be DHT11. You may like to try the following tutorial: (1) "How to set up temperature and humidity sensor (DHT11) on raspberry Pi - Kookye":
http://kookye.com/2017/06/01/how-to-set-up-temperature-and-humidity-sensor-dht11-on-raspberry-pi-2/, ***It is important NOT to power DHT11 with 5V***, or you might fry your R[i: (2) Rpi3 might have been fried by wrongly connected DHT11 temparature sensor
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96560/rpi3-might-have-been-fried-by-wrongly-connected-dht11-temparature-sensor/96563#96563. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: it's am2302, sorry, you can see in the table Vcc = 3.3 to 6V

Comment: Ah, I am confused. Before I answered, I clicked your link and saw the blue sensor DHT11. Now I clicked it again and it changed to a white senor AM2302 (DHT22). Did you edit your link just now?

Comment: BTW white DHT22 is better than blue DHT11. Last time when I played with DHT22, I could not find any working library, so I DIYed my own library, but it is for Rpi3B and so out of dated: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1349307&hilit=DHT22+tlfong01#p1349307. Ah bed time. See you tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: yes I edited a link, I just need to know how to read from multiple devices like that connected to i2c hub

Comment: Anyway, Vcc > 3.3V might latch up your Rpi and fry it.

Comment: The other thing is that Elecrow does not have any DHT22 library or tutorial for Rpi.